# AmCharts v3 guides included to legend

Tags: angular, amcharts

I created a line chart in an Angular project with AmCharts v3 like this [one](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/duration-on-value-axis/)

I also add two guides(dashed lines) for valuesAxis with a minimum and maximum value like

```
{
  "dashLength": 5,
  "inside": true,
  "label": "Min Temp. Limit",
  "lineAlpha": 1,
  "lineThickness": 2,
  "color": "#a136a5",
  "lineColor": "#a136a5",
  "above": true,
  "value": null
}
```

I enable legend but it only shows the graphs but not the guides.

Is there anyway to add the guides to the legend?

Comment: Can you share a small demo project on stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

Guides aren't graph objects, hence why they aren't included in the legends. You can add a custom marker that represents your guide through the legend's [`data`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmLegend#data) array, along with setting [`combineLegend`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmLegend#combineLegend) to true:

```
legend: {
  // ...
  data: [{
    title: "Min Temp. Limit",
    color: "#a136a5",
    markerType: "line"
  }],
  combineLegend: true,
  // ...
}
```